# Working on a memory puzzle game in Python, is there any way to raise the fps, but keep the reveal speed in the beginning slow?

Tags: python

You can find the game at http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter3.html

These are the 2 lines of code that I need to change:

FPS = 60 # frames per second, the general speed of the program

REVEALSPEED = 2 # speed boxes' sliding reveals and covers

Answer (score 0):

By increasing the fps and making the reveal speed stay the same, your question will be solved.

Answer (score -1):

You could change the fps and increase it, but then just keep the reveal speed at the same rate.